# Can I be sure in property order using lodash assign method

Tags: javascript, lodash

using lodash assign method, can I do

```
_.assign(self, {
            inputContext: createAddonInputContext(),
            currentEmployee: _.first(self.inputContext.employeeList),
        });
```

the `currentEmployee` property value calculation depends on `inputContext` being assigned already. My question is, will this always work, or it can break in some environments i.e. when `currentEmployee` will be assigned first?
In other words, does the order in which properties appear in source object literal guarantee the same order when the  value are being evaluated? I'm aware that when we do for...in iteration over javascript object, the order isn not certain. Hence my question.

Comment: In fact, this will *never* work. The object literal and its properties are evaluated even before `assign` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the `currentEmploye` property value calculation depends on `inputContext` being assigned already.

Then you will need to assign them separately:

```
self.inputContext = createAddonInputContext();
self.currentEmployee = _.first(self.inputContext.employeeList);
```

> will this always work, or it can break in some environments i.e. when `currentEmployee` will be assigned first?

This *never* works, it will break in *all* environments. The object literal and its two property values are evaluated before the call to `assign` is executed and anything is assigned to `self`.

> Does the order in which properties appear in source object literal guarantee the same order when the value are being evaluated?

Yes, in fact object property values are always evaluated in source order, but this doesn't matter here, the values [are inaccessible as properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616202/1048572) before the whole object is created.